# php extension value not correct printed why?

Tags: php, c++, ubuntu, php-extension

I want to send an object through reference. The object represents a class

[test.php]

```
$car= new Car();
$car->l=1000;

$car2 = new Car2();
$car2->method($car);
```

[php_cod.cc]

```
PHP_METHOD(Car2, method)
{
    Car2 *car;
    Car obj11;
    zend_class_entry ce2;

     if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "o", &obj11) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }



    car2_object *obj = (car2_object *)zend_object_store_get_object(
        getThis() TSRMLS_CC);
    car2 = obj->car2;
    if (car2 != NULL) {
        //cout<<"in car 2 ref"<<endl;

        //car2->reference(s);
        (car2->method(obj11));
    }

}
```

[test.cc]

```
void Car2::method(Car &carr)
{
    cout<<"IN THE REFERENCE CLASS"<<carr.l<<endl; 

}
```

Where am I wrong?
THX! Appreciate

When I run php test.php the value vor carr.l is equal with 
155160836. WHY? Where am I wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the php part of code, `obj11` is an uninitalized pointer and that is being passed to Car2::method ( `(car2->method(*obj11));` ). So-

```
 cout<<"IN THE REFERENCE CLASS"<<carr.l<<endl; 
 // carr is a garbage reference and is causing the segmentation fault
```

Comment: how to solve this? what should i change in the php_code.cc code?

Comment: What is this call supposed to do ? `zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "o", &obj11)`

Comment: i solve the problem. I've changed to Car2 obj11. There is no segmentation fault, but the value for carr.ll is not 1000. It's 155160836. WHY?

Comment: that line takes's as argument an object/

Comment: `Car2 obj11;` `obj11` is an object whose members are not initialized/assigned anything. So, it's member variables has garbage.

Comment: but in test.php i do initialize the Car2 object. Look at test.php. That file calles vehicles.cc from php